how to get all alsa devices (aplay -L) in openSUSE TW?
So I've been using ubuntu but want to move to TW but the lack of support for "HiFi" USB DACs is stopping me right now. To explain better, when I ran "aplay -L" in Ubuntu I get this (non-relevant devices has been removed to shorten the display)
Basically, I do not see "hw" or "plughw" in TW. so I had to select "sysdefault" (or something else). This meant all music files are resampled to 48Khz (I know it's resampled as my DAC displays the sample rate it's receiving). I do not want this.
Any ideas on how to "fix"/what to do? Thanks
Some info on my setup:

On both Ubuntu and TW, I am running the default kernel (which I believe are both non-RT?)
I installed openSUSE using a TW installer ISO that I downloaded earlier in the week
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 right now on this laptop. But I believe it's not a problem with 22.04 as well because I setup a USFF that's dedicated for music listening and that's running Ubuntu Server 22.04
Both Ubuntu and TW has been updated to latest software/packages
"/proc/asound/cards" and "/proc/asound/modules" on both OS returns the same results


$ aplay -L
hw:CARD=x20,DEV=0
    xCORE USB Audio 2.0, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=x20,DEV=0
    xCORE USB Audio 2.0, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=x20
    xCORE USB Audio 2.0, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=x20,DEV=0
    xCORE USB Audio 2.0, USB Audio
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=x20,DEV=0
    xCORE USB Audio 2.0, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=x20,DEV=0
    xCORE USB Audio 2.0, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=x20,DEV=0
    xCORE USB Audio 2.0, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=x20,DEV=0
    xCORE USB Audio 2.0, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=x20,DEV=0
    xCORE USB Audio 2.0, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=x20,DEV=0
    xCORE USB Audio 2.0, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=x20,DEV=0
    xCORE USB Audio 2.0, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=x20,DEV=0
    xCORE USB Audio 2.0, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=x20
    xCORE USB Audio 2.0
    USB Stream Output


